# How to integrate cardinalcommerce authentication processing in a flash and Asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

- Our Asp.net//Flash team doing a shopping cart project.
- We are integrating First Data Alternative payment gateway.
- Shopping cart items are selected through flash and our asp.net team taking the data from flash and integrating the first data alternative payment.
- We have already integrated first data payment gateway.
- Now we want to integrate First Data Alternative payment gateway.
- Please help our team to do so